# forceNetwork not displaying, no code errors returned

Tags: r, d3.js, networkd3

I am creating a networkD3 forceNetwork(), but after I cleared my env vars in RStudio the network would not display in my browser when I ran the code a second time. Any idea why? No code errors. Var output is below.

```
library(networkD3)
library(igraph)
setwd("C:\\Users\\King\\Desktop\\SNA_Rcode")
csv<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\King\\Desktop\\Analysis\\mc_with_0_and_MI.csv")

df<-data.frame(csv$stat.deaths,csv[,4],csv$stat.mob)#damage delt on deaths, mob kills (is color)
#2 mode. interactive model
#g1 <- simpleNetwork(df) ; htmltools::html_print(g1, viewer = utils::browseURL)#DISPLAYS CORRECTLY
df <- df[!duplicated(df[,2]),]
df[,2] <- paste("", df[,2], sep="")
#setup
g <- graph.data.frame(df,directed=F)
links<-as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g)) #set name to number so calculate link correctly
links$V1<-as.numeric(as.character(links$V1))
links$V2<-as.numeric(as.character(links$V2))
colnames(links)<-c("source","target")
link_list<-(links-1)
#######################DOESNT WORK LIKE EXPECTED......replaces NA with 2 instead of 999
color_groups<-df[,3]# color based on mob kills
color_groups <- ifelse(as.numeric(color_groups) < 10, 1, 
                       ifelse(as.numeric(color_groups) >= 30, 3, 2))
color_groups[is.na(color_groups)]<-999 #replace NA with 999

names<-0:(length(color_groups)-1)
node_list <- data.frame(name=names, group=color_groups)

profanity<-forceNetwork(Links = link_list, Nodes = node_list,Source = "source", Target = "target", NodeID = "name",Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, colourScale = "d3.scale.category10()",charge=-100)
htmltools::html_print(profanity, viewer = utils::browseURL)
```

After running all the above code (with a clear env):

```
    > head(link_list,20)
       source target
    1       6   1169
    2       1    839
    3       1   2594
    4       7   5409
    5      11   2719
    6       5   1719
    7       7    179
    8       2   1989
    9       4   3444
    10      0   2249
    11      1   1964
    12      0   3344
    13      6   4479
    14      6   2224
    15      7   3869
    16      5   2459
    17      3   1704
    18     -1   2479
    19      5   3494
    20      4   1869

> head(node_list,20)
   name group
1     0     2
2     1     1
3     2     2
4     3     3
5     4     1
6     5     2
7     6     1
8     7     2
9     8     2
10    9     2
11   10     1
12   11     2
13   12     2
14   13     2
15   14     2
16   15     2
17   16     2
18   17     2
19   18     2
20   19     2
```

Comment: I'm looking for people to help me get this into a function, that we could maybe push to igraph or the forceNetwork people. https://github.com/gregmacfarlane/forceGraph/tree/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to set the names for the vertices using:

```
V(g)$name<-1:104
```

after I initialized the graph (g)

Comment: People don't realize just how important this is  - I wasted 2 days with garbage values and no progress because this wasn't in the docs

Comment: Thank you! No error and no plot appearing really stinks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `link_list$source` and `link_list$target` vectors appear to include indexes that are not in your `node_list`, e.g. `-1` and `2249`... or the values in those vectors are not what they are supposed to be...

The `source` and `target` vectors in the `Links` data frame must be numeric, and their values refer to the index of the node in the `Nodes` data frame which they represent (zero-indexed, unlike R, because it's used by the JavaScript code).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in which `forceNetwork` ran fine with no issue but found a different cause in my case -
My `Links` dataframe had been filtered and its IDs were *no longer consecutive*. For example, an ID list of `0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12` **will not work**. It must be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`