# Plotting forceNetwork diagram in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a project to plot mobile OS update times, using forceNetwork from D3 in R.  I've successfully plotted a few basic iterations using simpleNetwork, but cannot get the more complicated network to correctly plot.

Have read up on a few posts on this subject, including this one ([forceNetwork not displaying any edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426708/forcenetwork-not-displaying-any-edges)), but haven't been able to deduce the answer.

Like the guy in the post above, I'm able to plot the graph with lots of nodes, but cannot get them to connect.  Here is what I'm looking to achieve with the nodes:

- At center, the mobile operating system (Android and iOS)
- First outer edge, the OEMs (Motorola, Samsung, Apple, etc.)
- Second outer edge, the mobile devices, connected to the appropriate OEMs

For links, I'd like to model accordingly:

- first link between mobile OS and OEM, is just connecting them since there is a known connection (i.e. Motorola makes Android devices, Apple makes iOS devices).  For this, I'm using the numerical variable "promised", which should have a "1" for each record to establish the connection.
- Second link, between OEM and device, should be "how.long" (i.e. how long it took them to deliver on the actual upgrade)...ideally, I want the length of the link between the nodes to be derived from the length of time it took to deliver on the actual upgrade.

I've created "misNodes" and "misLinks" with the following data:

misNodes <- data.frame(operating.system, OEM, Device)
misLinks <- data.frame(promised, updated, how.long)

I've made a bit of progress plotting with legend and key, but haven't been able to structure in the desired way, nor have I had much success drawing the desired linkages.  Here are my best attempts, so far:

```
#Try plotting
forceNetwork(Links=misLinks, Nodes=misNodes, Source="promised", Target="updated", Value="how.long", NodeID="Device", Group="OEM", width=1000, height=1000, opacity=1, zoom=TRUE, legend=TRUE, bounded=TRUE) #doesn't work, but making progress

forceNetwork(Links=misLinks, Nodes=misNodes, Source="promised", Target="how.long", NodeID="Device", Group="OEM", width=800, height=800, opacity=1, zoom=TRUE, legend=TRUE, bounded=TRUE)

forceNetwork(Links=misLinks, Nodes=misNodes, Source="promised", Target="how.long", Value="promised", NodeID="Device", Group="OEM", width=800, height=800, opacity=1, zoom=TRUE, legend=TRUE, bounded=TRUE)

    str(misLinks)
'data.frame':   74 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ promised: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ updated : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ how.long: num  6 3 1 4 1 6 6 6 6 0 ...

str(misNodes)
'data.frame':   74 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ operating.system: Factor w/ 2 levels "Android","iOS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OEM             : Factor w/ 7 levels "Apple","HTC",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 ...
 $ Device          : Factor w/ 74 levels "Atrix HD","Atrix HD (developer edition)",..: 7 54 55 56 57 58 59 22 20 21 ...
```

Any tips would be appreciated...

EDIT: added some data:

```
head(misLinks)
promised updated how.long
1        1       1        6
2        1       1        3
3        1       1        1
4        1       1        4
5        1       1        1
6        1       1        6

head(misNodes)
  operating.system OEM                    Device
1          Android HTC                 Droid DNA
2          Android HTC                       One
3          Android HTC   One (developer edition)
4          Android HTC            One (dual sim)
5          Android HTC One (Google Play Edition)
6          Android HTC                   One Max
```

Here is what the third plot above shows when you run it (please note, I'm holding cursor over the "one" node in image to illustrate...for some reason, those ones connect):
[image: forceNetwork(Links=misLinks, Nodes=misNodes, Source="promised", Target="how.long", Value="promised", NodeID="Device", Group="OEM", width=800, height=800, opacity=1, zoom=TRUE, legend=TRUE, bounded=TRUE)]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, here is some of the data from each (please see EDIT above).

Comment: Any ideas from anybody?  Would love to get this figured out...