# (R) forceNetwork warning message : "It looks like Source/Target is not zero-indexed. This is required in JavaScript and so your plot may not render"

Tags: r, plot, graph, nodes, networkd3

I am trying to create a graph network in using the networkD3 library. I consulted the following stackoverflow answer ([forceNetwork not displaying any edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426708/forcenetwork-not-displaying-any-edges)) and followed the instructions, making sure that the "source/target is zero centered" by "subtracting 1" from the source target and the source link. But I am still getting a warning message indicating that they have not been centered, and no graph is being produced.

First, I simulated some fake data

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

#create file from which to sample from
x5 <- sample(1:1000000000, 2000, replace=T)
#convert to data frame
x5 = as.data.frame(x5)

#create first file (take a random sample from the created file)
source = sample_n(x5, 1000)
#create second file (take a random sample from the created file)
target = sample_n(x5, 1000)

#combine
links = cbind(source,target)
#create dataframe
links = data.frame(links)
#rename column names
colnames(links) <- c("source","target")

#convert to factors
links$source = as.factor(links$source)
links$target = as.factor(links$target)

#add value column (I think all values should be 1?)
links$value =1


#create nodes 
#first create group (since I have no information, I will assume everyone is in the same group)

nodes = links
nodes$nodeID = nodes$source
nodes$group = 1
nodes = nodes[,c(4,5)]
```

Then, I followed the instructions from the stackoverflow plot to create the graph:

```
# build a new Nodes data frame that includes every 
# unique node found in links$source and links$target
nodes_complete <- data.frame(nodeID = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))

# add groups already identified in your original Nodes data frame
nodes_complete$group <- nodes$group[match(nodes_complete$nodeID, nodes$nodeID)]

# convert your links$source and links$target nodes to their index
# in the new Nodes data frame (zero-indexed)
links$source <- match(links$source, nodes_complete$nodeID) - 1
links$target <- match(links$target, nodes_complete$nodeID) - 1

# now the forceNetwork function will run as expected
library(networkD3)
forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes_complete, Source = "source", 
             Target = "target", NodeID = "nodeID", Group = "group", 
             opacity = 0.8, 
             colourScale = "d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);")
```

Yet I still get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
It looks like Source/Target is not zero-indexed. This is required in JavaScript and so your plot may not render.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you delete these lines in your code, it will work

```
links$source = as.factor(links$source)
links$target = as.factor(links$target)
```