# R Networkd3 white screen and no error message

Tags: r, networkd3

I've tried to use [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) with the follwing data:

```
> head(network)
   source target
1      1      1
2      1      4
3      1     11
4      1     12
5      1     23
6      1     41


> head(no)
         no group
1    AL USA     1
2    AR USA     1
3 Argentina     1
4 Australia     1
5 AUSTRALIA     1
6   Austria     1
```

and code:

```
forceNetwork(Links = network, Nodes = no, NodeID = "no",
         Source = "source", Target = "target", 
         Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

My problem is nothing happens. :( No error message...the viewer screen just stays white?

Any Ideas?

Cheers, Cliff

---

```
simpleNetwork(network)
```

works by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here: [Going crazy with forceNetwork in R: no edges displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194888/going-crazy-with-forcenetwork-in-r-no-edges-displayed)

My data had to be 0-based instead of 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

`source` and `target` should be numeric vectors, giving the index of the node in your nodes data frame (0 indexed).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've modified source and target. The problem is unfortunately still there.